# Change the size of width in yas-describle-table

Tags: emacs, org-mode, yasnippet

Upon checking `yas-describe-table`, I find

```
state name                               key 
#+ATTR_HTML: :width ..                   width
```

Click into it

```
# -*- mode: snippet -*-
# name: #+ATTR_HTML: :width ...
# --
#+ATTR_HTML: :width ${1:500px}
```

I plan to change the size of width from 500px to 700 px, but it prompts that

```
cond: Buffer is read-only: #<buffer width>
```

How could change the size of width?

Comment: `yas-describe-table` does not seem to be either a standard emacs function, nor a `yasnippet` function (all of those seem to have a `yas/` prefix and there does not seem to be a `yas/describe-table`). So I think we'll need to know its definition (or at least where it came from).

Comment: snippets are editable for me from `yas-describe-tables`, try `C-x C-q` from the snippet buffer (or `M-x read-only-mode`) and see if you can edit and save the snippet